# How to store live scallops?

Tags: seafood, shellfish

I bought some really fresh live scallops from the pier today. I was planning on making something with them immediately as it is best when absolutely fresh. However plans change and I wasn't able to cook them. This leaves me with a couple options:

I.)Store live and then prepare them the next day the same way I would have otherwise.

II.)Process them now by taking out muscle and discarding the rest and then keep the muscles in the fridge.

Intuitively it would seem like its best to keep them alive as long as possible. If this is the case then what is the best way to store them?

Note that I am not trying to preserve them very long. Just pushing back my plans by one day.

Answer (score 1):

Bivalves need to be kept alive until you are ready to cook or serve them. Keep them cool on the ride home from the pier.

- They are best stored in an airtight container.
- Put that container in a bowl of ice.
- Keep them in the coldest part of your refrigerator.

Comment: Airtight?  They need to breath, right?

Comment: They live in the sea, the air in the container should be enough to keep them alive for a few hours. They won't live or stay fresh for much longer than that anyway. The container has to be sealed as seafood attracts and multiplies bacteria quite quickly and you don't want to run the risk of cross contaminating either them or the rest of your food.